# Move related products after product summary?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to move the related products in this position:

> woocommerce_after_single_product_summary

Currently is in:

> woocommerce_after_single_product

You can check the positions [here](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/#tab-additional_information).

This is what I tried so far, I added this code in the single-product.php file:

```
<?php
 do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
 woocommerce_output_related_products();
?>
```

The problem with this is that duplicates the related products section.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Related Product Section is already in the woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.** 
Now You need to change the priority. Related Products Priority is given: 20 
If You want to show it before product tab section, then you have to make the priority less than 10. such as 9

```
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_product_summary.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
```

Let's see how to change the priority. 
First of all, I have removed the default priority of related_products.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
```

Finally, I have reset the pririty as 9.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 9);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but the remove_action is not working in my functions.php, any idea why isn't working?

Comment: I think it works. Whether it works to test it, you can use only remove_action() first.
Then, it will remove the related product section. (
share me the link )